# Displaying Pie Chart Using Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I have had success displaying and manipulating bar charts but I cannot figure out how to work the pie charts. When I use the inspect tool I can see that something is there. I am using the following code:
Chart.js CDN:

Canvas container for the graph:

Javascript taken from the docs:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");       
var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type:"pie",
    data: [3, 4],
    options: {
        animation:{
            animateScale:true
        }
    }
});
```

Amy advise will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. For more see [Pie chart Usage](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-example-usage). Comment if any confusion

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Chart.js — Pie Chart Demo</h2>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation ([Chart.js - Pie & Doughnut Charts](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart)), the `data` variable should have had following structure:

```
data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],
    datasets: [{
    backgroundColor: [ /* backgroundColor is optional */
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
    ], 
    data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
}]
```

}

as I see it, this is the problem in your case.